# What's the best way to wait for the server using react?

Tags: javascript

I'm using const instead of var.

```
const allUsers = Users.find().fetch();

if (allUsers.length === 0) {
  createDummyUsers();
  // I want to say allUsers = createDummyUsers(); instead but allUsers is const and it's async
}
```

The problem is I can't reassign allUsers (if length === 0) because it's a const. What's the convention to call an async function and await the response here? This is the function I'm trying to wait for:

```
const createDummyUsers = function () {
  console.log('// seeding users…');
  createUser('Bruce', 'dummyuser1@telescopeapp.org');
  createUser('Arnold', 'dummyuser2@telescopeapp.org');
  createUser('Julia', 'dummyuser3@telescopeapp.org');
};
```

Comment: can't you use `let` instead?

Comment: You can use Promises here. `createDummyUsers` would return a resolved promise with the user data, and you can access it like, createDummyUsers().then(function(allUsers) { console.log(allUsers) })

Comment: otherwise, make `fetch` a promise, and `createDummyUsers` a promise.
fetch().then(result => result.length > 0 ? result : createDummyUsers())